# How to create a mapping in WireMock to ensure exact number of headers in request?

Tags: java, unit-testing, http-headers, wiremock

Here is a basic setup of `WireMock` server with matching of two headers.

I would like to ensure that server matches request when **only explicitly given headers** are present in the request.

How to express intention "with exactly two headers" or "without other headers"?

```
WireMockServer server = createServer();

server.givenThat(
    WireMock.get(urlPathEqualTo("/my/path"))
            .withHeader("x-first" , equalTo("abc"))
            .withHeader("x-second," , equalTo("xyz")) 

            // how to ensure there are no other headers ?

            .willReturn(ok("{}"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get all server events/interactions that took place since the last reset(). This way you can see exactly how your request 'arrived' on the wiremock side: what body, which headers etc. Hope this helps
[wiremock verifying](https://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/)